Glyph origin of 器
Somehow I'm not convinced of the classic interpretation that there is a dog 犬 needed to guard four vessels 口. Did 器 used to mean something else before being borrowed to mean "organ" or "tool"?

What causes you to think there are other interpretations?

From what I can tell according to some other interpretations, 器 may be composed of semantics 犬 (dog) + 㗊 (many mouths) and its original meaning is probably "the barking of a dog," which is the original form of 狺.

Or alternatively, 器 may be derived from 喪 for the sense of "burial container."

I don't think there's enough direct evidence for a definite explanation, but here's something which I think is plausible, and is fairly common among academic circles.




時期字體
字形
參考資料




商甲

粹470合集30781


商甲

前6.2.5合集1082


西周金

Ｘ簋集成4097


春秋金

秦公簋集成4315


戰國・楚簡

2.251包山楚簡


東漢隸

禮器碑



「器」 (喪器, burial device, funerary urn, or grave goods) is derived from the same character as the original form of 「喪」 (Baxter-Sagart OC: /*s-mˤaŋ/, mourning, burial), which is 「⿴㗊桑」; here, 「桑」 (/*[s]ˤaŋ/, mulberry tree, phonetic component of 「喪」) was later corrupted into 「犬」 to form the modern 「器」. 「㗊」 (multiple mouths > crying, wailing for someone's death) remained as a semantic component in both 「喪」 and 「器」.
The link between 「器」, spirit/funeral rites, and mulberry is hinted by several mentions in received texts; for example:



《禮儀・士喪禮》
鬠笄用桑，長四寸，纋中。
Etiquette and Ceremonial: Mourning rites for the common officer
Hairpins for top-knots shall use mulberry, four cùn in length, to fix the knot in the centre.




《公羊傳・文公二年》
虞主用桑，練主用栗。
Gōngyáng Commentary: Second year of the Duke of Wén
Post-burial memorial rite tablets shall employ mulberry, while first anniversary memorial rite tablets shall employ chestnut.




《周禮・春官宗伯》
典瑞：掌玉瑞、玉器之藏，辨其名物與其用事，設其服飾。
Rites of Zhōu: Offices of Spring
The 「典瑞」 is in charge of the storage of jade tablets of accord (瑞) and jade devices of spiritual rites (器), distinguishing them by their topic and usage, and establishing their proper adornments.



To be clear, the characters 「器」 and 「喪」 represent completely different words, so the association of 「器」 with  「喪」 is indicative or ideographic (rather than linguistic).

References:

《古文字詁林》, volume 2, pp. 649-650

